# QT application hangs when started in debug mode

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qml, qtwebengine

I tried to create a simple QT application, where the frontend is HTML and a native backend. I used code from the QtWebView (QML) and QWebChannel examples to build a small demo.

If I start the release build of the application, everything works as expected, except, you can't really debug the release build. If I start the debug build, the application starts, then it stops as if a debug breakpoint was hit (I have no breakpoints set) and after I press resume, the application hangs forever.

I'm currently using a Windows 7 x86 machine for development. QT Version is 5.5.

I uploaded the demo application to my google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byc0Zui_4XuxaUc5MmJlWlo0M28/view?usp=sharing

Any ideas why the debug version won't work?

Edit: Here is my code, as requested.

TestSuite.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick webengine webchannel websockets
CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    shared/websocketclientwrapper.cpp \
    shared/websockettransport.cpp \
    Log.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)

HEADERS += \
    shared/websocketclientwrapper.h \
    shared/websockettransport.h \
    Log.h
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtWebEngine/QtWebEngine>
#include <QWebSocketServer>
#include <QWebChannel>

// From the webchannel example
#include "shared/websocketclientwrapper.h"
#include "shared/websockettransport.h"

// Simple class with 1 method "void logMessage(const QString &msg);" which writes a string to qDebug()
#include"Log.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QtWebEngine::initialize();

    //setup WebSocket server
    QWebSocketServer server(QStringLiteral("QWebChannelServer"), QWebSocketServer::NonSecureMode);
    if (!server.listen(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 12344)) {
        qFatal("Failed to open web socket server.");
        return 1;
    }

    //wrap WebSocket clients in QWebChannelAbstractTransport objects
    //see:qtwebchannel/examples/webchannel/standalone
    WebSocketClientWrapper clientWrapper(&server);

    //setup the channel and connect to WebSocket clients
    QWebChannel channel;


    // Register Objects
    Log l;
    channel.registerObject("Log", &l);


    // Start Application
    QObject::connect(&clientWrapper, &WebSocketClientWrapper::clientConnected,
                     &channel, &QWebChannel::connectTo);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtWebEngine 1.1

Window {
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    visible: true
    WebEngineView {
        id: webview
        url: "qrc:/index.html"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>m2suite</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <a onclick="Log.logMessage('test')">Log.sendMessage</a><br>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var Log;

var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:12344/");

socket.onopen=function(){
    var c = new QWebChannel(socket, function(channel) {
        //connection to server succeeded, objectsavailablevia:
        Log = channel.objects.Log;
    });
}
```

Comment: if it hang in debug just pause the application and inspect where the threads are located. Resumes, and pause again. It will give you a hint. Anyway post the code inside your question.

Comment: It looks like it first stops inside Chrome_IOThread. If I click resume, I am not able to pause again. All buttons, except stop, are greyed out.